# Why can't the Google sites HTML box load a CSS script linked with URL?

Tags: css, html, google-sites

I'm mostly certain that I set up my HTML script correctly, and made sure that the needed CSS file would be hosted in a shared folder on Google Drive, correctly cited, etc.

However, when I copy my HTML code into the box, and save it all, the editor always throes this error: `1+12 - 125: failed to load external url navigator.css`

While I would think that linking the CSS file to the HTML code regularly, as I posted below, I only see so many issues coming up with CSS linking, and even more worrying, is that the Google support documentation ([here](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en)) says that an HTML box can't 'refer' to external code, including what I believe may be such a CSS file.

`<link href="http://[mixed aplhanumeric subdomain].googledrive.com/host/[shared folder's 'mixed' address]/navigator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Given that, would anyone know a simple workaround to linking the HTML to the CSS code in the Google sites HTML box?

Comment: can you go to `http://[mixed aplhanumeric subdomain].googledrive.com/host/[shared folder's 'mixed' address]/navigator.css` directly?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows an example with the CSS in `<script>` tags.  I don't perceive any indication that including CSS from an external file is allowed.  The documentation explicitly states that `<link>` tags are not allowed.  The reason why Google Sites can't load CSS in a linked file, is because link tags are not allowed.  You're only choice is to include the CSS in `<style>` tags.

There is an alternative though.  You can create an Apps Script HTML Service application with separate HTML and CSS files, and then put the Apps Script application into your Google Site.

[Apps Script HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

Comment: I did notice how the documentation stated that external links are prohibited, and While I may have other questions later, I 'd just like to give you my thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Css on Google SItes , you can use directly. not to use link.